# Github Actions cannot find package.json in repo

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using Github Actions for the first time and I am struggling to execute my whole workflow . This is my YAML so far:

```
name: Deploy authn configuration to prod
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download files from the current repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"

  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Install Auth0 Deploy CLI Action
        run: npm install -i -g auth0-deploy-cli

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: install
    steps:
      - name: Change to root directory
        run: |
          ls -la 
          cd ./auth0_infrastructure
          ls -la
      - name: Import config to prod tenant
        env:
          AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.PROD_AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET }}
        run: npm run import:staging
```

I get this error:

```
Run ls -la 
/home/runner/work/_temp/0cfef2ac-60f2-4f6a-8016-d1cc5ec1deaf.sh: line 2: cd: ./auth0_infrastructure: No such file or directory
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Jul 18 13:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker 4096 Jul 18 13:21 ..
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

If I remove the 'change to root directory step' in the install job, my error becomes:

```
Run npm run import:staging
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/auth0_infrastructure/auth0_infrastructure/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/auth0_infrastructure/auth0_infrastructure/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-07-18T13_13_02_927Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
.
├── README.md
├── config
│   ├── prod.json
│   └── staging.json
├── config.json
├── databases
│   └── Username-Password-Authentication
│       ├── change_password.js
│       ├── create.js
│       ├── delete.js
│       ├── get_user.js
│       ├── login.js
│       └── verify.js
├── docs
│   └── HOWTO.md
├── emailTemplates
├── hooks
├── package.json
├── pages
├── rules
│   └── Microsoft Profile Picture.js
└── tenant.yaml
```

I have used 3 separate jobs as I was under the impression that the steps in a singular job ran in parallel rather than sequentially .

Comment: Could you share the repository structure in the question, informing where the package.json is located? _Observation: note that **each job** will use a new ubuntu-runner instance, so in this specific case, I'm note sure you would need 3 different jobs to perform what you want (the setup on the first job won't be use in the following jobs)._

Comment: @GuiFalourd please find the updated repo structure- I was attempting to form sequential steps-  is there a way to perform all the steps in 1 job sequentially than in parallel?

Comment: Ok. In your case, the `auth0_infrastructure` would be the repository name?

Comment: To perform the jobs in sequence, you need to use the `job: needs: [previous_job_name]` subtype. [Here is the official documentation about this configuration](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running three different jobs which are dependent.

So, your yaml file should looks like below

```yaml
name: Deploy authn configuration to prod
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download files from the current repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"
      - name: build
        run: <build_command>

  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Download files from the current repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"
      - name: Install Auth0 Deploy CLI Action
        run: npm install -i -g auth0-deploy-cli

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: install
    steps:
      - name: Download files from the current repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"
      - name: Change to root directory
        run: |
          ls -la 
          cd ./auth0_infrastructure
          ls -la
      - name: Import config to prod tenant
        env:
          AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.PROD_AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET }}
        run: npm run import:staging
```

The issue is, each jobs run in a different machine, and you have to clone the repo and setup NodeJS on each job.

To share build between your jobs, checkout this action[Upload Artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact), [Download Artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact) where you can upload your build from build job, and download the same in deploy job.

Comment: "The issue is, each jobs run in a different machine".  This reminder saved me, thank you!