# Github actions deploy to azure, cannot find package.json

Tags: azure, github-actions

So this isue has happened rather recently, we've deployed hundreds of times using this method to our web app hosted on azure, but for some reason its constantly failing out in the installation phase of our deployment, stating that it cant find the package.json file i've been over the code a dozen times now trying to find out what changed but im not noticing anything. so im hoping someone notices something i dont with the workflow file. I referenced this article here: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023195/github-actions-cannot-find-package-json-in-repo) However, it doesnt quite fix my flow.

here is the `yml` file:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      #zips the repo, helps with transferring a large amount of files
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      # removes the release.zip from being pushed to the final deployment
      - name: Remove File
        # You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
        # uses: JesseTG/rm@94440f309afcc4c37e6bf63eb0feca9e94dee5a3
        uses: JesseTG/rm@v1.0.0
        with:
        # The file path to remove
          path: release.zip
      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'redacted'
          slot-name: 'redacted'
          publish-profile: ${{ redacted }}
          package: .
```

on every push i get the same error that it cannot find the package.json of the project even though the project structure hasnt changed since our last successful push.
structure:

```
--project:
---github/workflows
---public
---src
--.gitignore
--.prettierrc.cjs
--package-lock.json
--package.json
## this is file is just for azure, it essentially sets up a small node server, that serves up the build folders index.js
--server.js
```

Comment: the zipping seems unnecessary. In fact the whole build stage seems unnecessary, as your building is actually being done in the deploy stage, after the zip is reinflated.

Comment: look at the change history of the yml file. Does it match up to where the deployment started to fail?

Comment: to me, it looks like you're extracting the artifact content and not going to the path before trying to run npm install.

Comment: @DerekGusoff As im learning more about the stages of a Github deployment action your correct, as i have it that stage is essentially not needed, which i will change later. the last change to the yml was made several months ago when i was attempting to try to get azure to build the build folder, but i reversed back to a working flow, and its been the same for nearly the applications existence.
Not sure what you mean, but i've had this workflow the same for near a year now with no errors, so im not sure what would change that caused the issue.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio, Not sure what you mean, but i've had this workflow the same for near a year now with no errors, so im not sure what would change that caused the issue.

Comment: then compare the structure of the artifact

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio not sure what you mean

Comment: I do think what you're putting inside release.zip is not the same as it used to be. (different folders/names), reason why the packages.json could not be found

Comment: npm install assumes you're in the same level as package.json file. If that's not true, you'll get the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the solutions provided in the github ticket #[47](https://github.com/Azure/actions/issues/47) help you to fix the issue.

I have also tried reproducing from my end by taking a NodeJS web app and able to build and deploy successfully.

**Project structure:**
[image]

**yml file:**

```yaml
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy

# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - pravwebapp1

on:  
push:  
branches:  
    - main  
workflow_dispatch:

jobs:  
build:  
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Set up Node.js version
    uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: '18.x'

  - name: npm install, build, and test
    run: |
      npm install
      npm run build --if-present

  - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: node-app
      path: .
deploy:  
runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
needs: build  
environment:  
name: ‘Production’  
url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

steps:
  - name: Download artifact from build job
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: node-app

  - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
    id: deploy-to-webapp
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    with:
      app-name: 'pravwebapp1'
      slot-name: 'Production'
      publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREXXXXXXXXPROFILE_C2039D6D16XXXXXX }}
      package: .
```

I could build and deploy the web app successfully as shown below:

[image]

[image]